# JavaFX Transition animation memory overflow

Tags: java, linux, javafx, javafx-8, fedora-21

I have a problem with creating JavaFX applications. 
My computer was installed Fedora 21 64bit 8G RAM .

When you create JavaFX TranslateTransition to move labels from one to the other side comes up loads of RAM to 100 % and CPU up to 60 %

When checking jconsole heap memory does not exceed 80MB .

Here's the code

```
...
translateTransition = new TranslateTransition();
translateTransition.setNode(label);
translateTransition.setFromX(position); 
translateTransition.setToX(-position);
translateTransition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(120));
translateTransition.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE); 
translateTransition.play();

...
```

Comment: you calling the method from MainApplication thread or from a JavaFx Thread(Platform.runLater()) ?? if you do it on the main thread then this your problem , because the platform tries to do many concurrent jobs on the same thread causing the impact in perfomance you mentioned

Comment: I tested the app on Windows OS and the problem with filling the  memory did not exist

Comment: are you sure you have properly installed jdk 1.8 in fedora?

Comment: yes i am  $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)